# Converting an oracle query to MySQL query

Tags: mysql, oracle

I'm trying to convert this query from Oracle to MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE SCT_201301_UMLS_SYN 
AS SELECT DISTINCT A.SCUI "SNOMED_CODE", A.STR "SNOMED_DISPLAY_NAME"
   , B.STR "UMLS_SYNONYM" 
FROM MRCONSO A, MRCONSO_UMLS B 
WHERE A.SCUI IN (SELECT referencedComponentId 
                 FROM SnomedCTtoICD10) 
AND A.SAB='SNOMEDCT' 
AND A.SUPPRESS='N' 
AND A.TTY='PT' 
AND B.LAT='ENG' 
AND B.SUPPRESS='N' 
AND A.CUI=B.CUI
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Seems like [it should be the same](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html) syntax.  Are you getting an error?

Comment: It's not a syntax problem, so you should post you error log. Check it in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc9b9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an older version of MySQL, then you might have a problem with the performance of `in`.  Here is an alternative, which should work in both MySQL and Oracle:

```
CREATE TABLE SCT_201301_UMLS_SYN 
AS SELECT DISTINCT A.SCUI "SNOMED_CODE", A.STR "SNOMED_DISPLAY_NAME"
   , B.STR "UMLS_SYNONYM" 
FROM MRCONSO A join
     MRCONSO_UMLS B
     on A.CUI = B.CUI
WHERE exists (SELECT 1
              FROM SnomedCTtoICD10 s
              where s.referencedComponentId  = a.scui) 
AND A.SAB='SNOMEDCT' 
AND A.SUPPRESS='N' 
AND A.TTY='PT' 
AND B.LAT='ENG' 
AND B.SUPPRESS='N'
```

Comment: This seems to work, but it fails on lost connection...I think because the tables are so large it's losing the connection still?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why your statement didn't work, but you could try it using ANSI syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE SCT_201301_UMLS_SYN 
AS 
SELECT DISTINCT A.SCUI "SNOMED_CODE", A.STR "SNOMED_DISPLAY_NAME" , B.STR "UMLS_SYNONYM" 
  FROM MRCONSO A
       join MRCONSO_UMLS B 
         using (CUI)
 WHERE A.SCUI IN (SELECT referencedComponentId 
                    FROM SnomedCTtoICD10) 
   AND A.SAB='SNOMEDCT' 
   AND A.SUPPRESS='N' 
   AND A.TTY='PT' 
   AND B.LAT='ENG' 
   AND B.SUPPRESS='N'
;
```

Comment: It appears to be running now if it doesn't throw back an error I'll accept this as correct shortly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That query should work just fine in MySQL (>=5.1).  MySQL should accept that syntax.

But there could be some differences. By default, Oracle is "case sensitive" and MySQL is not. So one difference you might run into is the number of rows eliminated by the DISTINCT keyword. (You could also encounter this difference between Oracle and Oracle, or MySQL and MySQL.)

Obviously, the tables referenced by the SELECT statement need to exist on the local MySQL database, and the user running the query needs to have SELECT privilege on them. (In Oracle, these references might be references to views or to synonyms, rather than tables. And those views and synonyms might reference objects in other schemas.)

```
MRCONSO
MRCONSO_UMLS
SnomedCTtoICD10
```

It's not possible to run a query on MySQL to retrieve data from a remote Oracle database. So, for this query to work, those objects will need exist on the local MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle people define the way the tables should be joined just by adding more conditions to the 'Where' clause.   MySql people define the join within the join statement. So move

```
AND B.LAT='ENG' 
AND B.SUPPRESS='N' 
AND A.CUI=B.CUI
```

to be replaced with

```
FROM MRCONSO A join MRCONSO_UMLS B
on B.LAT='ENG' 
AND B.SUPPRESS='N' 
AND A.CUI=B.CUI
```