# Converting an Oracle to MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle

Can anyone help or advise? I am new to Oracle I have this query which needs to be converted to a MySQL Query

```
with dset as (
select count(column_1) as Volumes, to_char(creation_date,'MM-YYYY') as 
Month, REPLACE(record_type, 3, 2) as RecordType from
table_1 where
transaction_type = 'PG' and
category = 'CCB' and
trunc(creation_date) >= to_date(?1, 'DD/MM/YYYY') and
trunc(creation_date) <= to_date(?2, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
group by to_char(creation_date,'MM-YYYY'), REPLACE(record_type, 3, 2)
)
   SELECT    x.DateMonth
      ,MAX(DECODE(x.RecordType, '1', x.Volumes)) CONSUMER
      ,MAX(DECODE(x.RecordType, '2', x.Volumes)) COMMERCIAL
   FROM    (
          SELECT    r.DateMonth
                  ,r.RecordType
                  ,r.Volumes
          FROM    dset r
      ) x
 GROUP BY x.DatetMonth
```

What would be the best approach to get this query working in MySQL.

Many Thanks

Comment: related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600071/converting-an-oracle-query-to-mysql-query?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Which version of mysql?

Comment: @P.Salmon I am using SQL Server Managemnt Studio v17.6

Comment: SSMS is not the data base (and is normally used with sql server not oracle or mysql) so the question remains which version of mysql?

Comment: I tried running query within SSMS select @@version its says version 13.0 does this help?

Comment: I bet it also contains the words Microsoft SQL Server and if it does this question is tagged incorrectly (it should be tagged sqlserver). It's important to get this basic info right - mysql and sqlserver are not the same and if there is uncertainty about the tags at best you will get a delayed response at worst a solution which works but not in the db you wanted.

Comment: Yes it does @P.Salmon Microsoft SQL Server 2016. Does this mean the syntax will be different?

Comment: There are enourmous differences between SQLserver and mysql not least that Common table expressions (ie with...) have only very recently made it in to production in mysql. Between Oracle and sqlserver there are also many differences - you won't find to_char or to_date functions in sqlserver for example.

Answer (score 0):

SQL generally follows certain standards across the different database systems. So your query should mostly work on all SQL platforms. However some of the built in functions are different.

The best approach is to just try and run the query and see what errors it generates and work through them.

You will have to look at the documentation for the `convert` MSSQL function, as you will be needing that.

If you get stuck you can ask a more specific question about what it is you are stuck on.

Comment: Since migrating an Oracle database to SQL Server a lot of the database table names have been changed which is where I am getting the errors. I wanted to check that the query in general would be ok to run in SQL.  So thank you all for your advise on this. I will attempt at running the query and  work with the errors generated.

Comment: Hi In my query in SSMS I am trying to figure out bits of the query above. So far in my recordType column i get returned 1 and 2 I want to run this query in SSMS `,MAX(DECODE(x.RecordType, '1', x.Volumes)) CONSUMER
 ,MAX(DECODE(x.RecordType, '2', x.Volumes)) COMMERCIAL` the end result should give me 1 = consumer and 2 = commercial any idea what I'm doing wrong? full query above works in Oracle but not in SSMS.

Comment: There is no `DECODE` function in MSSQL. Lookup the `case` expression or the ternary function `iif`